# Auto Focus QR Scanner

Tags: flutter, android-camera, qr-code, flutter-dependencies, autofocus

I am developing a flutter app that uses qr_code_scanner dependence(https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner).

I want the QrView to autofocus, but I can't find a solution.
How do I auto focus the Camera for qr_code_scanner?

Comment: Has anyone found any solutions?

Comment: hello were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little late man, but I managed to do it as follows.

When we set the `cameraFacing` property to `CameraFacing.back`, you start using the rear camera of the device, allowing the operating system to manage the camera's autofocus.

Therefore, if your device supports autofocus, it will adjust the focus automatically to try to capture the QR code more accurately.

You can make this small adjustment to your creation method by adding the following snippet at the end of the method:

```
void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) async {
// your code...
controller.flipCamera();
await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 400));
controller.flipCamera();
}
```

A small delay is added with **Future.delayed()** to allow the camera to adjust before flipping it again!